# Java main function won't compile with a method in it

Tags: java

I am using Netbeans to learn basic Java stuff right now, and I have looked around and I cannot figure out what is wrong with this. I am unable to make any kind of method in the "main" function because it does not compile. I get an error saying

> error: illegal start of expression: public String method(int a){

```
    public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       public String method(int a){
           return "a";
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In here as a beginner you have done little bit wrong 
You can`t create a Function in side main
In the main Method we normally use it to call the functions we created so create a separate class and call it using main method

```
  public class JavaApplication3 {
    public void main(String[] args) {

    method(1);

  }
  public String method(int a){
    return "a";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, we can call a method inside another method using object, but we can't create a method inside another method.

Example:

```
public class JavaApplication3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JavaApplication3 Objet1 = new JavaApplication3();
       Objet1.method(5);
    }
    public String method(int a){
        return "a";
    }
}
```